# How to convert a text file stream to a json file stream

Tags: json, apache-nifi, update-attributes

I'm using apache nifi and I have a stream of text files that comes from a splitText processor with the following content, 2 lines: the first line is the id and the second line is the word. For example:

```
1
games
```

and I need to make json from this file, for example:

```
{
"id": 1,
"word": "games"
}
```

I tried to enter the values ​​from the lines into the file attributes using `updateAttribute`, but I don’t know how to access the first and second lines, as I understand they are separated by the `“\n”` character, but I don’t know how to get exactly the first line to create the id, and how to get the second row for the word attribute. If I can make attributes, then I can make json from attributes using `AttributesToJSON`

Thank you in advance for your cooperation!

Comment: here is a good example that uses ConvertRecord with csv reader and json writer:
https://www.projectpro.io/recipes/read-csv-files-and-convert-data-into-json-format-using-nifi-controller-services your source (2 lines) is not really csv, but you can set the new line `\n` as a field separator - so it will be considered as a new column..

Comment: I recommend `ScriptedReader` (https://www.alasdairb.com/posts/getting-started-with-nifis-scriptedreader-by-processing-key-value-pairs-part-1)

Answer (score 0):

You can use ExtractGrok processor , its good for reading some unstructured data and generate json output. You can read more about the Grok Expression here:

[GrokExperssio](https://nifi.apache.org/docs/nifi-docs/components/org.apache.nifi/nifi-record-serialization-services-nar/1.24.0/org.apache.nifi.grok.GrokReader/additionalDetails.html)

For your case I used the following Expression:

```
%{INT:id}\n%{WORD:word}
```

[image]

This gave me the following json output:

```
{"id":"1","word":"games"}
```

You can use jolt transformation to convert id to integer using the spec:

```
[
  {
    "operation": "modify-overwrite-beta",
    "spec": {
      "id": "=toInteger(@(1,id))"
    }
  }
]
```

Hope that helps

Comment: With this approach you probably wouldn't need the SplitText processor either.